# Scraping data with beautiful soup and writing to a csv file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to write the contents of the following HTML to a csv file.

```
            <div class="metadata">

                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li class="salary">&#163;24,000 - &#163;27,500 per annum</li>
                        <li class="time">Permanent, full-time</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="location">
                        Reading
                        <span style="display: none;">Berkshire</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </div>
```

The outcome of this HTML code looks like:

```
            

                
                    £24,000 - £27,500 per annum
                        Permanent, full-time
                
                
                    
                        Reading
                        Berkshire
```

I wrote the following python code to **scrape** this (with BeautifulSoup):

```
 metadata=job.find("div", attrs={"class":"metadata"})
    metadata=job.find("div", attrs={"class":"metadata"})
    salary=metadata.find("li", attrs={"class": "salary"}) 
    salary=salary.text
    time=metadata.find("li", attrs={"class": "time"})
    location=metadata.find("li", attrs={"class": "location"})
    df=(salary, time, location)
    df.to_csv(mydata)
```

I have two problems:

1. Location has two parts (province and city) which I'm not able to isolate. Ideally, I want to have two variables called the province and the city which get the first and the second parts of the location variable, respectively.
2. I have many such observations and I would like to write them into a csv file but I cannot figure how to do that. Ideally, I would like my excel file to have 4 columns for salary, time, province, and city.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. exactly  -  Could you also add your expected output and some of code you tried to write csv. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I tried to improve the code with the information you requested. I'm sorry if it is still not good. I am a new learner of webscrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #1, it's hard to tell what the problem is without more information. In your example, are "Reading" and "Berkshire" the province and city, respectively, and is city (e.g. "Berkshire") always wrapped in a span?

As to #2, it should be fairly straightforward to do this with Python's native [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and [file handling](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-plain-text-files-in-python-3). Here's an example which presumes you have your data in an array of arrays, one salary/type/location pair per array, called `data`:

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  for row in data:
    csv_writer.write(row)
```

That's about the least code you can use to do it, but you can go deeper on how the file is written, adding a header row, or tweaking the format of the CSV as needed if you check out the documentation.

Comment: Hello Jim, thanks a lot for your answer! Yes,  in my example,  "Reading" and "Berkshire" are the province and city, respectively, and the city (e.g. "Berkshire") is always wrapped in a span.

Comment: When I tried your csv code, Python gives the NameError: "ame 'w' is not defined"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to quote it. Definitely check out the documentation, it has a lot of good examples. I wrote that code w/o running it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `location.text` you mean to get whole text from that `<li>` tag. You need to use **.next[[see docs]](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#next%20and%20previous)** to get outer text, rather whole together. In order to get 'Berkshire' you need to address to span tag and scrape its text. So in your case:

```
location1 = metadata.find('li', class_='location').next # this will give you Reading in a raw format
clean_location1 = location1.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '') # convert location1 to a clean format
location2 = metadata.find('li', class_='location').span.text # this will give you Berkshire
```

Since `location1` will come with extra newlines and spaces, it is needed to reformat it after scraping. Your result would look like this:

```
clean_location1 --> Reading
location2 --> Berkshire
```

As for writing this information in a `.csv` file, this [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) would solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried your code and location2 looks perfect. location1 on the other hand has spaces between different rows when I apply your code to multiple article classes. Do you have any suggestions for cleaning the spaces between different rows for location"?

Comment: @KartalTibet try to print out location one as raw string and check what is extra there. if there are anything that you don't want, you can just use `.replace('<unwanted_char>', '')` to convert it to empty string. Check how i dealt with first one in that case and created `clean_location1`